# What is $PU(n,m)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

I have seen this notation in several places. I tried to read about it in Wikipedia,

> In terms of matrices, elements of U(n) are complex n×n unitary matrices, and elements of the centre are diagonal matrices equal to eiθ multiplied by the identity matrix. Thus, elements of PU(n) correspond to equivalence classes of unitary matrices under multiplication by a constant phase θ

I'm not sure what "correspond to equivalence classes of unitary matrices under multiplication by a constant phase" means.

If I want to write this group explicitly, what would be the description of this set?

$ PU\left(n,m\right)=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}A_{n\times n} & B_{n\times m}\\
C_{m\times n} & D_{m\times m}
\end{pmatrix}\in U\left(n,m\right):\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace such\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace that...\right\}  $

**Note:** I am using the definition of $U(n,m)$ as

$ U\left(n,m\right)=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}A_{n\times n} & B_{n\times m}\\
C_{m\times n} & D_{m\times m}
\end{pmatrix}\in GL_{n+m}\left(\mathbb{C}\right):AA^{*}-BB^{*}=I_{n},\thinspace DD^{*}-CC^{*}=I_{m},AC^{*}=BD^{*}\right\}  $

If someone can describe the elements of $PU$ explicitly it would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would a quotient be a subgroup?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is actually impossible: $PU(n,m)$ does not embed in $U(n,m)$. It is easier to prove in the category of Lie group isomorphisms rather, although it is also true on the level of abstract groups. Aside: Do you know what a quotient group is? It consists of the equivalence classes they are talking about.

Comment: @MoisheKohan What is the equivalence relation defined here?

Comment: It is $A\sim B$ iff there exists a unit complex number $e^{i\phi}$ such that $A=e^{i\phi} B$. As the quotient group,  $PU(n,m)$ is simply the quotient of $U(n,m)$ by the subgroup consisting of scalar matrices. They could simply have said this in the W article, but, likely, it was edited by a physicist.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you explain what  "$PU(n,m) $ is simply the quotient of $U(n,m)$ by the subgroup consisting of scalar matrices " means? I understand that PU(n,m) is the quoteint group by the equivalence relation you defined, but what do the subgroup of scalar matrices has to do with it?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Also, is this the right definition for $U(1,1)$? $ U\left(1,1\right)=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}\in GL_{2}\left(\mathbb{C}\right):|a|^{2}-|b|^{2}=1,\thinspace|d|^{2}-|c|^{2}=1,a\overline{c}=b\overline{d}\right\}  $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a general definition. Suppose that $G$ is a subgroup of $GL(n,{\mathbb C})$. Then the group $PG$ is defined as the projection $\pi(G)$ of $G$ to the group $PGL(n,{\mathbb C})$ under the quotient map
$$
\pi: GL(n,{\mathbb C})\to PGL(n,{\mathbb C}). 
$$
The group $PGL(n,{\mathbb C})$ is the quotient of $GL(n,{\mathbb C})$ by its center, the subgroup of scalar complex matrices ${\mathbb C}^\times$, i.e. matrices of the form
$$
\lambda I_n, \lambda\in {\mathbb C}^\times,
$$
where $I_n\in GL(n,{\mathbb C})$ is the identity matrix.

It is very seldom true that the subgroup $PG$ can be embedded in $GL(n,{\mathbb C})$. For instance, the group $PU(p,q)$ cannot be embedded (as a subgroup) in $GL(p+q, {\mathbb C})$, unless $p+q=1$, which is, of course, utterly uninteresting. I am not going to prove this.

Nevertheless, the group $PGL(n,{\mathbb C})$ does embed in
$GL(N,{\mathbb C})$ for $N=n^2-1$. Hence, $PU(p,q)$ does embed in
$GL((p+q)^2-1,{\mathbb C})$ as a subgroup of invariants of some  polynomials (but I find it painful to write down these invariants explicitly).

For a subgroup $G< GL(n,{\mathbb C})$ the projection $\pi(G)$ is naturally isomorphic to the quotient $G/C_G$, where $C_G= G\cap {\mathbb C}^\times$.

Consider now the case when $G=U(p,q)$, $p+q=n$. My favorite definition of this group (same as [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group#Indefinite_forms)) is as the subgroup of $GL(n,{\mathbb C})$ consisting of matrices which preserve the pseudo-hermitian product on ${\mathbb C}^n$:
$$
\langle v, w\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^p v_k \bar{w}_k - \sum_{k=p+1}^n v_k \bar{w}_k,
$$
where $v=(v_1,...,v_n), w=(w_1,...,w_n)$. I find your definition to be nonstandard. I think, you are using transposes of the standard matrix representation, i.e. you are considering the action on the row-vectors rather than column-vectors. There are situations when this is useful, I just prefer the standard notation. My suggestion to you would be to use the standard notation as well. In particular, I prefer not to answer your question about $U(1,1)$ since our notation are different. However, for the rest of the answer, the difference is irrelevant.

Then the intersection of $G=U(p,q)$ with the subgroup of scalar matrices consists of scalar matrices of the form
$$
\lambda I_n, \lambda\in {\mathbb C}^\times, |\lambda|=1. 
$$
I will use the notation $H$ for this intersection (I do not think there is a standard notation here).

Answering your question in the comments: When do two matrices $a, b\in U(p,q)$ have the same projection to the $PU(p,q)$? It is when the two $H$-cosets are equal: $aH=bH$. Equivalently, when $b\in aH$. Equivalently, when there is $\lambda\in {\mathbb C}^\times, |\lambda|=1$ such that $b=\lambda a$.

Comment: So two matrices $A,B$ belong to the same class in PGL if there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^{\times} $ such that $A=\lambda\cdot B $ ?

Comment: @FreeZe: That's what I wrote.

Comment: Im sorry Im familier with the term "quotient set" only when there's equivalence realtion in the background, so its not intuitive for me to understnad what the realtion that is defined naturally when you say "quotient of $GL(n\mathbb{C} $ by its subgroup.

Comment: I see: This means you did not take an abstract algebra class. Given a group $G$ and a subgroup $H< G$ one defines a new set $G/H$ whose elements are the "cosets" $gH$, subsets of $G$ of that form. It is a nice exercise to check that this defines an equivalence relation by $g_1\sim g_2$ iff $g_1H=g_2H$. Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group).

Comment: @FreeZe: After checking your profile, I realized that you are an EE student. My suggestion is to take at least one Abstract Algebra course (group theory) and the Real Analysis sequence, if you can. It will help you later on.

Comment: actually im a student of both EE and mathematics. Next semester I will take the group theory course (hopefully). Thanks for your help!